# Listening to dynamically created toggle button in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello all I am implementing a control board with dynamically created toggle buttons where the number of toggle buttons is also dynamic, I am having a hard time appending a function to the dynamically created buttons,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 ToggleButton tb[i] = new ToggleButton(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tbparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (90, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tbparams.setMargins(120, 0, 0, 0);
            tb[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgtoggle);
            tb[i].setId(i+1);
            tb[i].setText("toggle_btn"+i+1);
            tb[i].setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
            tb[i].setLayoutParams(tbparams);
}
```

Comment: what is issue to creating toggle button?

Comment: tb.setOnClickListener() ? should work what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a CheckedChangeListener as:

```
    OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new 
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
}
```

and set it as:

```
tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

You can retrieve the id of the toggled button by invoking `buttonView.getId()` in `onCheckedChanged` method and do specific task based on Id.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being this late, i hope someone will take it as useful

```
 tb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(handleOnClick(tb[i],tb[i].getId(),
tb[i].getTag(),iv[i],iv[i].getTag()));
/*Function declartion for dynamic Toggle button listening provided a tag is provide to uniquely identify the dyanmic buttons*/
```

//Toggle button function

```
    private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener handleOnClick(final ToggleButton toggleButton, final int id, final Object tag ) {
............................ //Do your wish
}
```